# Formulário só submete com a tecla Enter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, e-commerce

Dentro do backoffice de uma loja baseada em Prestashop V.1.6.1.3.

Quando tento cadastrar um produto, acontece problema muito estranho que não apresenta erro em nada mesmo usando o modo debug ligado:

```
define('_PS_DEBUG_DEV_', true);
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

**Problema:** Quando seleciono o botão **submit**, usando a navegação com tab e clico em ENTER, ele submete o formulário, porém quando clico no botão ele não envia o formulário.

**Considerações:**
Quando estou usando o Fedora Linux, com o Chrome Versão 52.0.2743.82 (64-bit), o formulário submete com click e salva o produto sem problemas. Porém, quando submeto o formulário usando o virtualbox, com o Windows 7, com o Chorme mais atual: 54.0.2840.59, ele simplesmente só salva o produto depois da quinta tentativa com (click) ou através de tab até chegar no botão e pressionar "ENTER".

O mais estranho é que mesmo apagando todo o cache do navegador, e testando em várias máquinas, com "windows 7, windows 8 e windows 10..." este erro ocorre, somente usando o Firefox no Windows e no meu Linux não apresentou este problema. Isso é um comportamento muito estranho... Por isso, estou sem ideia do que poderia ser este erro, e não faço ideia de como poderia consertar o problema.

**Código:**

Esta é a cabeça do formulário:

```
<form id="product_form" class="form-horizontal col-lg-10 col-md-9" action="index.php?controller=AdminProducts&amp;token=9aa71815d1823d502542e0ddedffdcdb&amp;addproduct" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="product" novalidate="novalidate">
```

E estes são os botões do rodapé:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <a href="index.php?controller=AdminProducts&amp;token=9aa71815d1823d502542e0ddedffdcdb" class="btn btn-default"><i class="process-icon-cancel"></i> Cancelar</a>
    <button type="submit" name="submitAddproduct" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><i class="process-icon-save"></i> Salvar</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submitAddproductAndStay" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><i class="process-icon-save"></i> Salvar e permanecer</button>
```

Trecho do javascript do **admin.js**:

```
function bindSwapSave()
{
    if ($('#selectedSwap option').length !== 0)
        $('#selectedSwap option').attr('selected', 'selected');
    else
        $('#availableSwap option').attr('selected', 'selected');
}

function bindSwapButton(prefix_button, prefix_select_remove, prefix_select_add)
{
    $('#'+prefix_button+'Swap').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#' + prefix_select_remove + 'Swap option:selected').each(function() {
            $('#' + prefix_select_add + 'Swap').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $('#selectedSwap option').prop('selected', true);
    });
}

/** make sure that all the swap id is present in the dom to prevent mistake **/
    if (typeof $('#addSwap') !== undefined && typeof $("#removeSwap") !== undefined &&
        typeof $('#selectedSwap') !== undefined && typeof $('#availableSwap') !== undefined)
    {
        bindSwapButton('add', 'available', 'selected');
        bindSwapButton('remove', 'selected', 'available');

        $('button:submit').click(bindSwapSave);

    }
```

**PS:** Esta loja utiliza [**smarty**](http://www.smarty.net).

O comportamento normal, era quando clicar, salvar e apresentar uma mensagem de sucesso.
Mas mesmo deixando os campos obrigatórios em branco, ele nem sequer validou. E no console,  Mesmo com o Javascript habilitado. Parece bruxaria.

Veja na imagem como está sendo enviado sem erro de código, porém não submete:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
E esta é no Fedora Linux, que submete normal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Novas informações:**
>   Acabei de descobrir que se trata do ícone do disquete que esta sobrepondo o botão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não sei se esse seria o caso, mas já testou se isso não é um problema de css? Já que vc descobriu que o ícone que sobrepõe o botão, inspecione o css desse ícone. É possível que seja algo do tipo.

Comment: É algo do tipo, porém não sei o que fazer ainda.

Comment: Sua loja está online ou só local?

Comment: Tenho ela em produção, local e em homologação. Por quê?

Comment: Existe alguma forma de fazer este ícone ficar não selecionável usando css?

Comment: Se o ícone está sobrepondo o botão podemos ter algumas possibilidades: A mais provável na minha opinião é que o ícone pode não estar dentro do elemento `<button>` ou `<input>`, o que faz com que ele não seja clicável. O que eu te sugiro fazer é: Clique com o direito no ícone > inspecionar e veja como está organizado o html do botão e as regras do css. Se achar necessário pode postar uma imagem ou o bloco de código para analisarmos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

```
.bootstrap .btn.btn-default i {
 color:#555,
 pointer-events:none; /* aqui retiro qualquer evento no ícone */ 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O que poderia ser feito é ir diretamente via `Javascript` e desabilitar o evento de clique do botão. Em alguns casos muito raros o `Javascript` confunde a ação do clique de um botão que possua imagens como "ícones"...

Segue código que desabilita:

```
elemento.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Quem deu downvote poderia pelo menos dizer o por que? Obg.

Comment: +1. Não sei quem foi cara, sinto muito por isso. Mas obrigado pela ajuda, mesmo já tendo resolvido o caso usando css, mas penso que a pessoa que te negativou não deve ter compreendido sua ideia, já que poderia funcionar para o elemento `<i class="process-icon-save">` que fica dentro do botão: `var elemento = document.querySelector('.process-icon-save');`

Comment: Isso mesmo! Obrigado pelo up e boa sorte!